# Debugging a sudoers regex pattern for changing the IP address using sed in /etc/hosts file

Tags: regex, sed, sudoers

I would like to change the IP address in /etc/hosts file using sed

Original file:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.180.106.103   abc.lab.com       abc
10.180.104.149   def.lab.com       def
10.180.105.145   ghi.lab.com       ghi
```

How to change only the IP address like below :

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.180.106.126    abc.lab.com       abc
10.180.106.135    def.lab.com       def
10.180.104.39     ghi.lab.com       ghi
```

I was able to replace the "new-ipaddress" details using the sed command `/usr/bin/sed -i -e "s/10.180.104.5/10.180.106.126/g" /etc/hosts`

format eg: `sed -i 's/old-ipaddress/new-ipaddress/g' /etc/hosts`

How can I add the sudoers regex pattern for the "new-ipaddress" place for changing the IPV4 IP address dynamically using sudoers?

I tried with `/usr/bin/sed -i -e "s/10.180.104.5/*.*.*.*/g" /etc/hosts` but it is not working.

Comment: You want to get new ip address from ` /etc/sudoers` file?  What is your expected output ?

Comment: @DigvijayS please find my reply below

Answer (score 0):

Hi I’m looking for the regex pattern in sudoers to replace the iPadddress in the /etc/host file using sed command

```
Sudo usr/bin/sed -i -e "s/10.180.106.103/*.*.*.*/g" /etc/hosts
```

The above regex is not working with Sudo to replace the old iPad dress 10.180.106.103 with 10.180.106.126

Looking for the sudoers regex pattern to replace with any new-ipaddress ( eg 10.180.106.126).

Thanks!